# pointer related queries

Tags: c, pointers

Guys i have few queries in pointers. Kindly help to resolve them

```
char a[]="this is an array of characters"; // declaration type 1 
char *b="this is an array of characters";//  declaration type 2
```

question.1 : what is the difference between these 2 types of declaration ?

```
    printf("%s",*b); // gives a segmentation fault
    printf("%s",b); // displays the string
```

question.2 : i didn't get how is it working

```
    char *d=malloc(sizeof(char)); // 1)
    scanf("%s",d); // 2)
    printf("%s",d);// 3)
```

question.3 how many bytes are being allocated to the pointer c? 
when i try to input a string, it takes just a word and not the whole string. why so ?

```
    char c=malloc(sizeof(char)); // 4)
    scanf("%c",c); // 5)
    printf("%c",c);// 6)
```

question.4 when i try to input a charcter why does it throw a segmentation fault?

Thanks in advance.. Waiting for your reply guys..

Comment: Code snippet 3 would not compile without warning. 2+3: Read `man scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char a[]="this is an array of characters"; // declaration type 1 
char *b="this is an array of characters";//  declaration type 2
```

Here you are declaring two variables, `a` and `b`, and initializing them. `"this is an array of characters"` is a string literal, which in C has type array of char. `a` has type array of char. In this specific case, the array does not get converted to a pointer, and `a` gets initialized with the array `"this is an array of characters"`. `b` has type pointer to char, the array gets converted to a pointer, and `b` gets initialized with a pointer to the array `"this is an array of characters"`.

```
printf("%s",*b); // gives a segmentation fault
printf("%s",b); // displays the string
```

In an expression, `*b` dereferences the pointer `b`, so it evaluates to the char pointed by `b`, i.e: `T`. This is not an address (which is what "%s" is expecting), so you get undefined behavior, most probably a crash (but don't try to do this on embedded systems, you could get mysterious behaviour and corrupted data, which is worse than a crash). In the second case, `%s` expects a pointer to a char, gets it, and can proceed to do its thing.

```
char *d=malloc(sizeof(char)); // 1)
scanf("%s",d); // 2)
printf("%s",d);// 3)
```

In C, `sizeof` returns the size in bytes of an object (= region of storage). In C, a char is defined to be the same as a byte, which has at least 8 bits, but can have more (but some standards put additional restrictions, e.g: POSIX requires 8-bit bytes, i.e: octets). So, you are allocating 1 byte. When you call `scanf()`, it writes in the memory pointed to by `d` without restraint, overwriting everything in sight. `scanf()` allows maximum field widths, so:

- Allocate more memory, at least enough for what you want + 1 terminating ASCII NUL.
- Tell `scanf()` to stop, e.g: `scanf("%19s")` for a maximum 19 characters (you'll need 20 bytes to store that, counting the terminating ASCII NUL).

And last (if *markdown* lets me):

```
char c=malloc(sizeof(char)); // 4)
scanf("%c",c); // 5)
printf("%c",c);// 6)
```

`c` is not a pointer, so you are trying to store an address where you shouldn't. In `scanf`, `"%c"` expects a pointer to char, which should point to an object (=region of storage) with enough space for the specified field width, 1 by default. Since `c` is not a pointer, the above may crash in some platforms (and cause worse things on others).

Comment: in the 2nd question, how is *b getting dereferenced?

Comment: @anonymous: `*b` is not getting dereferenced, `b` is. In an expression, unary `*` is the dereference operator.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%s",*b); // gives a segmentation fault
printf("%s",b); // displays the string
```

the %s expects a pointer to array of chars.

```
char *c=malloc(sizeof(char)); // you are allocating only 1 byte aka char, not array of char!
scanf("%s",c); // you need pass a pointer to array, not a pointer to char
printf("%s",c);// you are printing a array of chars, but you are sending a char
```

you need do this:

```
int sizeofstring = 200; // max size of buffer
char *c = malloc(sizeof(char))*sizeofstring; //almost equals to declare char c[200]
scanf("%s",c);
printf("%s",c);
```

> question.3 how many bytes are being allocated to the pointer c? when i
>   try to input a string, it takes just a word and not the whole string.
>   why so ?

In your code, you only are allocating 1 byte because sizeof(char) = 1byte = 8bit, you need allocate sizeof(char)*N, were N is your "string" size.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems in your code.

Question 1: The difference is:

- `a` gets allocated in writable memory, the so-called `data` segment. Here you can read and write as much as you want. `sizeof a` is the length of the string plus 1, the so-called string terminator (just a null byte).
- `b`, however, is just a pointer to a string which is located in the `rodata`. That means, in a data area which is read only. `sizeof b` is whatever is the pointer size on your system, maybe 4 or 8 on a PC or 2 on many embedded systems.

Question 2: The `printf()` format wants a pointer to a string. With `*b`, you dereferene the pointer you have and give it the first byte of data, which is a `t` (ASCII 84 or something like that). The callee, however, treats it as a pointer, dereferences it and BAM.

With `b`, however, everything goes fine, as it is exactly the right call.

Question 3: `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates exactly one byte. `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, so the call is effectively `malloc(1)`. The input just takes a word because `%s` is defined that way.

Question 4:

```
char c=malloc(sizeof(char)); // 4)
```

shound give you a warning: `malloc()` returns a pointer which you try to put into a `char`. ITYM `char *`...

As you continue, you give that pointer to `scanf()`, which receives e.g. instead of `0x80043214` a mere `0x14`, interprets it as a pointer and BAM again.

The correct way would be

```
char * c=malloc(1024);
scanf("%1024s", c);
printf("%s", c);
```

Why? Well, you want to read a string. 1 byte is too small, better allocate more.

In `scanf()` you should take care that you don't allow reading more than your buffer can hold - thus the limitation in the format specifier.

and on printing, you should use `%s`, because you want the whole string to be printed and not only the first character. (At least, I suppose so.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers sir. Yea i got your answers but
then in question 2, how come is it dereferencing the pointer b ? its just trying to display the `the value which is being pointed by b`. please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ad Q1: The first is an array of chars with a *fixed* pointer a pointing to it.  `sizeof(a)` will return something like 20 (`strlen(a)+1`).  Trying to assign something to a (like `a = b`) will fail, since a is fixed.

The second is a pointer pointing to an array of char and hence is the sizeof(b) usually 4 on 32-bit or 8 on 64-bit.  Assigning something to b will work, since the pointer can take a new value.

Of course, *a or *b work on both.

Ad Q2: `printf()` with the %s argument takes a *pointer* to a char (those are the "strings" in C).  Hence, `printf("%s", *b)` will crash, since the "pointer" used by printf() will contain the byte value of *b.

What you *could* do, is `printf("%c", *b)`, but that would only print the first character.

Ad Q3: `sizeof(char)` is 1 (by definition), hence you allocate 1 byte.  The scanf will most likely read more than one byte (remember that each string will be terminated by a null character occupying one char).  Hence the scanf will trash memory, likely to cause memory sometime later on.

Ad 4: Maybe that's the trashed memory.

Answer (score -1):

Both declaration are the same.
b point to the first byte so when you say *b it's the first character.
    printf("%s", *b)
Will fail as %s accepts a pointer to a string.
char is one byte.